# How to add Wordpress sub category without select

Tags: categories

How do I add a wordpress sub category without select parent dropdown using text

[image: Wordpress Category]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom links to directly target the pages:

Dashboard>Appearance>Menu>Custom Links

See Image:[Wordpress Using Custom Links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5XYA.png)